# I can't find which element was clicked on an html table's cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find if out if a cell was clicked [but wasn't a span] on a cell.

I can find if a user clicks on a span on a cell with the below code:

```
$('.table tbody tr td').on('click', 'span', function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

But I need to find if a user hasn't clicked on a span.
Is it possible to do that using jQuery or JavaScript?

I've tried `:not(span)` with no success.

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: Mritunjay you're right. I'm sharing fiddle address; http://jsfiddle.net/vyL4hdpt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe event currentTarget ( `e.currentTarget` ) may help you here.

```
$('table tbody tr td').click(function(e){
    console.log(e.target); // Will output clicked element
});
```

Comment: This answer is the best practice [together @epascarello's response]. I've given credit..

Comment: Not sure how this is a "best practice" when it is adding tons of events. Also not sure how the answer was picked when you edited it to actually work....

Comment: Master @epascarello , I thought that is same thing with the `event` that was used by you. Your answer is masterful and already I've given credit that. But I thought this answer is more readable. You're right I shouldn't write *best practice* with my one year experience. Or without know what is the difference between `$('table tbody tr td')` and `$('.table tbody').on('click', 'td'``. Thank you again..

Comment: The problem with this solution is the fact it adds a click event to EVERY cell of the table. Yeah it works, but when the table as a lot of cells, that gets expensive. I am not sure what is harder to understand since it is the same code other than the fact the td is not in the selector. Learn about the power of event delegation, you will be using the more you code.

Answer (score 3):

Use the event target to get what was clicked and do the check in the function, not the selector.

```js
$('.table tbody').on('click', 'td', function(event) {
  var td = $(this);
  var elementClicked = $(event.target);
  if (elementClicked.is("span")) {
    console.log("Span was clicked in the td");
  } else {
    console.log("No span was clicked in the td");
  }
});
```

```css
table, tr, td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>NO SPAN</td>
      <td><span>Span around all text</span>
      </td>
      <td>Span wrapped around the word <span>HERE</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `var elementClicked - $(event.target);` that supposed to be an `=` sign?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the click event bubbling up from the span. i.e.

```
$('.table tbody tr td').on('click', function(){
    console.log(this);
});

$('.table tbody tr td span').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will listen on click of all `td` cells and search for spans inside them if no span is found the log will fire.

```
   $('td').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).find('span').length)
            console.log("no span in td")

    });
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yn6bfx3q/1/